# How to add lock symbol to my website using private SSL in https pages

Tags: php, https, security-certificate

I just purchased SSL for my website from hostgator, so that I can add lock symbol in my website, when users visit `https://www.mysite.com`

For example:

[image: SSL Certificate]

Now they have installed the certificate, but I am unable to make this thing visible on my site. When I am opening the site with `https://` it shows no lock symbol.

Please help me to show lock symbol and security certificate information when `https://` pages open in my PHP Script.

Comment: "add lock symbol" Please [read something about SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer) to understand, what that means. Most of your question will get answered just by reading this WP article.

Comment: As the screenshot shows, you are not connected to your website domain name, but to some subdomain of `hostgator.com` hence you see the certificate for it and not your domain. You have to fix your DNS and/or rewriting rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure that all resources from your page (images, scripts, css) are also loaded via https otherwise your page is not secure.

Comment: The lock symbol shows: You are connected to mysite.com, which is run by (unknown). Why this unknown? How can i change this?

Comment: If you buy an EV certificate (unknown) will be replaced with the physical address of your company. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

add this in header and it's working.

Comment: That has only browser support for 90% of users. https://caniuse.com/#feat=upgradeinsecurerequests It would be better to update the links to the insecure requests instead.